# Way to check that string contains two of the same characters?

Tags: python, string

Lets say I have:

```
str = "Hello! My name is Barney!"
```

Is there a one or two line method to check if this string contains two `!`?

Comment: And a slightly more intriguing variation would be quickly checking if there are any doubled characters...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can get the solution in one line easily with the `count` method of a string:

```
>>> # I named it 'mystr' because it is a bad practice to name a variable 'str'
>>> # Doing so overrides the built-in
>>> mystr = "Hello! My name is Barney!"
>>> mystr.count("!")
2
>>> if mystr.count("!") == 2:
...     print True
...
True
>>>
>>> # Just to explain further
>>> help(str.count)
Help on method_descriptor:

count(...)
    S.count(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in
    string S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are
    interpreted as in slice notation.

>>>
```

Comment: `if mystr.count('!') == 2: print True` could be more succinctly written as just `print mystr.count('!') == 2` if you want the possible `False` printout as well, which I assume you do in most cases.

Comment: @kqr - True.  I was just demonstrating using `count` in an `if` block.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`str.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.count) method:

```
>>> s = "Hello! My name is Barney!"
>>> s.count('!')
2
```

BTW, don't use `str` as variable name. It shadows builtin `str` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
str.count("!")
```

So:

```
if str.count("!") == 2:
   return True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of one liner ways to find the number of characters in a string:

```
string  = "Hello! My name is Barney!"
```

Ways:

```
string.count('!') == 2 #best way
```

or

```
len([x for x in string if x == '!']) == 2 #len of compresion with if
```

or

```
len(string)-len(string.replace('!','')) == 2 #len of string - len of string w/o character
```

or

```
string[string.find('!')+1:].find('!')>0 #find it, and find it again, at least twice
```

`count` is the best, but I love to think of other ways, because I sometimes find redundant code/variables that way, depending on what you are doing of course. Say if you already have the len of the string and the len of the string with the characters replaced in variables, for some other reason, then you can simply subtract those variables. Probably not the case, but something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Except [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), I think [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) is also a feasible way:

Python 2:

```
>>> len(filter(lambda x: x == '!', "Hello! My name is Barney!"))
2
```

Python 3:

```
>>> len(list(filter(lambda x: x == '!', "Hello! My name is Barney!")))
2
```